# How to render styled data of block using blockRendererFn?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have a little trouble in usage of Draft.js.

When I set up prop `blockRenderMap` equal to the map

```
{'unstyled': {
    element: MyCustomTextBlock
}}
```

then my component `MyCustomTextBlock` gets `props.children`.

So it can work like wrapper:

```
const MyCustomTextBlock = (props) => {
    return <div className="my-custom-text-block">{
        props.children
    }</div>
};
```

In the code above `props.children` are rendered as styled text. But when I replace `blockRenderMap` to `blockRendererFn`, I absolutely have no ideas how to insert styled text into my component. The method takes only argument which is `contentBlock`.

```
(contentBlock) => {
    if (contentBlock.getType() === 'unstyled') {
        return {
            component: MyCustomTextBlock
        };
    }
    return null;
}
```

So, may be anyone knows how to pass children to the wrapper or probably how to render them manually?

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Finally, I want to implement sortable blocks. And I need a way to render stylized text inside SortableElement (from react-sortable-hoc), because all my blocks should be custom sortable components.

Actually I have made it already using both blockRenderMap and blockRendererFn, but it seems a bit strange, like a hack.

Comment: then how about `https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/b7fadfffec410b3332e056767f627324ecc5b725/docs/APIReference-AtomicBlockUtils.md#moveatomicblock`